# Python fuzzy matching program running very slow

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 series:  Series A has 10k rows, Series B has 20k rows.
 I need to take each element of A, and find the best match from B and write that match as a column .
I did:

```
def find_it(row):

    return difflib.get_close_matches(row.col_A, df_B.col_B.astype(str), n=1, cutoff=.6)

df_A = pd.read_csv("C:/listA.csv")
df_B = pd.read_csv("C:/listB.csv")


df_A['MATCH_NAME'] = df_A.apply (lambda row: find_it(row),axis=1)
```

But this is running for over an hour. How can i make it more efficient? I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Peraphs you could try [FuzzySet](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzyset/) instead of difflib. This lib creates an index, so it should run in less time. Also, you only need to create the index, with `df_B.col_B`, once and then reuse it multiple times. difflib does not creates an index, so it does the job from scratch every time.

You create the index by adding items of col_B and then you send it as a parameter to your apply function, which should use the `get` method to find the best match. If you want to use a cutoff setting, the get method returns a score, which contains the value you can use to filter matches.

There is an easy example on the home page of the lib with everything you may need.